# How to read first array object from JSON using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a JSON file and I need to convert that into CSV. But my JSON file contains JSON object which is an array and my all attributes are in that array but the code I am trying converts the first object into a single value but in actual I want all those attributes from JSON object.

JSON file content

```json
{
  "leads": [
    {
      "id": "31Y2V29CH0X82",
      "product_type": "prelist"
    },
    {
      "id": "2N649TAJBA50Z",
      "product_type": "prelist"
    }
  ],
  "has_next_page": true,
  "next_cursor": "2022-07-27T20:02:13.856000-07:00"
}
```

Python code

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\Product_List.json')
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\New_Products.csv', index = None)
```

The output I am getting is as following

[image]

And the output I want

[image]

I want the attributes as CSV content with headers?

Comment: Check out `pd.json_normalize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to do this row by row.

```
data = {"leads": [{"id": "31Y2V29CH0X82", "product_type": "prelist"}, {"id": "2N649TAJBA50Z", "product_type": "prelist"}], "has_next_page": True,
"next_cursor": "2022-07-27T20:02:13.856000-07:00"}

headers = data.copy()
del headers['leads']
rows = []
for row in data['leads']:
    row.update( headers )
    rows.append( row )

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( rows )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
              id product_type  has_next_page                       next_cursor
0  31Y2V29CH0X82      prelist           True  2022-07-27T20:02:13.856000-07:00
1  2N649TAJBA50Z      prelist           True  2022-07-27T20:02:13.856000-07:00
```